# Insert vertical lines for each group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4,each = 7), year = rep(2012:2018, times = 4),  
              y = runif(28), start = rep(2012:2015,each = 7), end = rep(2014:2017,each = 7))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

How do I insert for each id, two vertical lines whose position are given by the respective start and end column?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add this geometry to your plot: `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = start))` ?

Comment: Maybe that : `ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = y)) + geom_line(aes(start)) + geom_line(aes(end)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
vlines <- dat %>% 
  select(id,start,end) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  gather(key = grp,value = x,start,end)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~id) +
  geom_vline(data = vlines,aes(xintercept = x))
```